# setting Arcgis world imagery as data source for a mosaic data set

Tags: arcgis-server, cartography, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have created a mosaic data set and want to set esri world imagery basemap as my data source but i am unable to connect to the server can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

Esri world imagery layer is already a mosaic "in the cloud".
I do not think you can download it and use it locally. You would also need a very large storage space if this was possible.

Comment: you can download the basemap imagery in jpg+jgw